# Dynamic generating images in a dynamically generated panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to generate dynamic images on a button click and drag it in a panel.

The panel which I will be adding the images into are also getting created dynamically on the click of a button. The problem is if I click on another button say add images (used for adding images dynamically) the added panel are getting hidden. And then again if I click on add panel button I can see the previously added panels + new panel.

Is this because of post back or something?

Here is my C# code:

```
private void addRow1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row_cnt; i++)
    {
        var row = new TableRow();
        var cell = new TableCell();
        var tbl = new Table();
        cell.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
        cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        var pnl1 = new Panel();
        pnl1.ID = "Panel" + i;
        pnl1.Width = Unit.Percentage(800);
        pnl1.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
        pnl1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 231, 229, 246);
        pnl1.Visible = true;
        pnl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        pnl1.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(2);
        cell.Controls.Add(pnl1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        TableMain.Rows.Add(row);
        pnl1.Controls.Add(tbl);
        tbl.ID = "tbl" + (i + 1);
        tbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        tbl.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        tbl.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);
        var tbl_row = new TableRow();
        var tbl_cell = new TableCell();
        tbl_cell.Height = Unit.Pixel(90);
        tbl_cell.Width = Unit.Pixel(20);
        tbl_cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        tbl_cell.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(2);
        tbl_row.Cells.Add(tbl_cell);
        tbl.Rows.Add(tbl_row);
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="div" runat="server" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow ">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD SLAB" OnClick="Button1Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="ADD IMAGE" OnClick="Button2Click" />
            <asp:Table ID="TableMain" runat="server" Border="0">
            </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written?

Comment: Please do not add code to comments, edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: not able to format it correctly as the site requires. New to the web site. Please can you help.

Comment: You can click the _edit_ link below your question, then paste your code, select it and hit Ctrl+K to format it...

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating controls dynamically, you have to add them on every post back.

In your code, when you add rows and cells to the table you don't save what is already there before... You should add your controls to the ViewState. From the documentation:

> View state's purpose in life is simple: it's there to persist state across postbacks. (For an ASP.NET Web page, its state is the property values of the controls that make up its control hierarchy.)

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for an understanding of the ViewState and to see how to use it.